# Error when reading a big file java: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I am trying to read a file with 12M lines from a csv file in java. Each line is in the format movieId1,MovieId2,SimilarityBetweenThem. 
I would like to read this file and put the content in a HashMap, where the key String is in the format Movie1,Movie2.

Everything works well until the lines around 5,2M lines, but in that moment I get this error :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I already tried to increase the heap size, but it didn't work.

The following is the piece of code that produces such an error:

```
        try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
                String[] csvLine;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    i++;
                    csvLine = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                    //a=new CoupleMovieKey(csvLine[0],csvLine[1]);
                    similarities.put(csvLine[0]+","+csvLine[1],(csvLine[2]));
                    System.out.println(""+i);

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Use a database. Sooner or later the file will be too big to fit into memory, again.

Comment: How big is your file? If it is some hundreds of MB it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It is bad practice to store huge collection in memory.. You have to think of alternatives..

Comment: It is just 220MB big

Comment: It is 'just' 220MB big *at the moment*, and already it doesn't fit into memory. The conclusion is inescapable.

Comment: Which are the alternatives beyond using database ? I need it in main memory in order to access an element very fast

Comment: What you need is not an alternative to a database but an *alternative to trying to load a 220MB+ file into main memory when it doesn't fit,* and a database is the obvious alternative.

Comment: If you want to access the file content itself without loading it, you can try https://github.com/fge/largetext. If you really want to load the whole content in memory then increase the memory size: 220 MB is not so big in this day and age (what is your ram size? what is using it?). Otherwise ... a database seems a very good choice.

Comment: *"I already tried to increase the heap size, but it didn't work."* you should be more precise than that. Numbers are king.